# Any Rest api to verify if user is first time user in cloudfoundary UAA

Tags: rest, open-source, cloudfoundry-uaa

i am New to cloud foundary UAA, and i am trying to check on if user is a first time user or not. if user is first time i need to make the user to reset the password. so for that i am trying to check on any rest apis that already available in cloud foundary UAA. Any leads would be appreciated.

I didnt find much info related to any of those api in cloud foundary UAA